# Working with bootstrap carousel and noticed that text I entered appears to get below the carousel even i changed positioning, z-index of the elements

Tags: html, css, css-position, carousel, bootstrap-5

I kept parent elements position relative and child element div absolute, but when i saw through my chrome pesticide its seems that my  is under carousel. I even tried keeping z-index of  greater than its parent but couldn’t solve it

```css
.carousel {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #ef8172;
}

.carousel-item {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}

.carousel-hope {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<section id="testimonial">
  <div id="" true " aria-label="Slide 1 "></button>
              <button type="button " data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators " data-bs-slide-to="1 " aria-label="Slide 2 "></button>
              <button type="button " data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators " data-bs-slide-to="2 " aria-label="Slide 3 "></button>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-inner ">
              <div class="carousel-item active ">
                  <div class="carousel-hope ">
                      <h2 class="messege ">sknff shdfhhcsndfa sbvncsuhf snhfvusdhv sajlfsanvfho</h2>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item ">
                  <div class="carousel-hope ">
                      <h2 class="messege ">sknff shdfhhcsndfa sbvncsuhf snhfvusdhv sajlfsanvfho</h2>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item ">
                  <div class="carousel-hope ">
                      <h2 class="messege ">sknff shdfhhcsndfa sbvncsuhf snhfvusdhv sajlfsanvfho</h2>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          
          <button class="carousel-control-prev " type="button " data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators " data-bs-slide="prev ">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon " aria-hidden="true "></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden ">Previous</span>
          </button>
          <button class="carousel-control-next " type="button " data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators " data-bs-slide="next ">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon " aria-hidden="true "></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden ">Next</span>
          </button>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: What is `carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide">` ? Can you please create a running code snippet? Read: [mcve].

Comment: Also please *"i have some text to appear on my carousel, but it seems like my text is getting under my carousel"* cannot be a question title. [edit] and improve your question. Read [ask].

Comment: I made a snippet of your code and formatted it to clearly show the syntax error it has